# Installing a large number of fonts in XP at once

Tags: windows-xp, fonts

Can you suggest a way for windows to recurse all the folders and subfolders (after unzipping) containing the fonts I recently acquired instead of having to install them one by one? There are about 200.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do a search in the folder where the unzipped fonts are, select all the fonts after the search is done, copy them, go to c:/windows/fonts and hit paste. Voila you are done.

Comment: Wait, you mean I can just drop the new font files into the windows/fonts folder directly? Perhaps I was mislead or I misread, I thought I had to install via "3. On the File menu, click Install New Font" found at this MS support page: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314960.

Comment: The Windows/Fonts directory is a Shell Extension that will take care of the registration for you when you paste.

Comment: If a font comes in two files, do I need to worry about pasting them together--will the "dump" as suggested by Guillermo work on account of this?

Comment: it will work, as vscjones said, the shell extension will take care of it.